# Insert row number into table

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am trying to insert a row number into a table. The row_number() function works when performing a select query but the query doesn't work when I use it as part of an INSERT INTO TABLE query. I have also tried via Create Table As Select but I get the same seemingly generic error.

```
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask (state=08S01,code=2)
```

Example: This does not work.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE tablea
SELECT
column1,
column2,
row_number() over (order by column2 desc)
FROM
tableb;
```

Example: This does work

```
SELECT
column1,
column2,
row_number() over (order by column2 desc)
FROM
tableb;
```

Any pointers? Thanks!

EDIT: I'm using Hive 1.1.0 as part of CDH 5.4.8.

Comment: Can you please specify the hive version on which you are getting error?

Comment: I completely forgot. I'm using Hive 1.1.0 as part of CDH 5.4.8.

Comment: I have executed the given script (In answer) on Hive 1.2.1 as part of HDP 2.3 and I do not have CDH

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried the thing you wanted to do and it is working. here is my HQL statements:

```
create table tablea (id int, string name);

insert into tablea values (1, 'test1');
insert into tablea values (2, 'test2');

create table tableb (id int, name string, row_num int);

insert into tableb select id, name, row_number() over ( order by name desc) from tablea;
select * from tableb;
```

**outcome**

```
+------------+--------------+-----------------+--+
| tableb.id  | tableb.name  | tableb.row_num  |
+------------+--------------+-----------------+--+
| 2          | test2        | 1               |
| 1          | test1        | 2               |
+------------+--------------+-----------------+--+
```

Comment: I ran this script and it works (swapped name and string in the first line). I must have another unrelated error. I'll mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

OK it looks like this is because the storage format was ORC. Setting the table to TEXTFILE and the problem goes away.